# Connecting to university LAN using Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: networking, server

I have been browsing much of AskUbuntu and other related forums, but no one quite seems to have the same issue as I have, so my search has not borne fruit of yet.

My intention is to set up a SSH server in my dorm room at college that I can connect to from anywhere using the IP of the computer.  In setting up the server computer, however, I am able to ping web addresses with 0% packet loss, but if I attempt to apt-get update or apt-get upgrade all packages fail to be fetched.  I use a username and password to connect to LAN, but have not been asked for either yet.  Please let me know if I can post any lines of output to help. Lspci and ifconfig have been included, in case they can help.  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
lspci:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)

ifconfig:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:bf:48:66:44:1b  
          inet addr:10.50.122.193  Bcast:10.50.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::12bf:48ff:fe66:441b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20846 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2210 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2201114 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:726442 (726.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to clarify first, you have a 10. address which means is a private address and you won't be able to access it from the Internet unless you have a port forward or DMZ. Most likely the university has isolation for the client computers (at least my university does), meaning that you can't talk to another computer in the network, they do this as a security measure.

Similar alternatives for this could be remote desktop such as team viewer (http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx), or reverse SSH (this is a more advance option and requires a third party server somewhere in the Internet such as amazon ec2), and I am sure there are more options out there.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy response.  That is true that teamviewer would be much easier, I currently use that; however, I wanted the personal experience of hosting a linux server.  After more troubleshooting, I found it was my own fault.  I was able to register the computer through the w3m terminal browser, so it was simply a web authentication issue.  Thank you for your help, I'm sorry if I inconvenienced you at all.